# Good triplets sum and divisor

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

> Given an array A of N integers. Find the number of good triplets `(i, j, k)`, where `i`, `j`, `k` are all distinct indices such that `0 < i , j , k <= N`. A good triplet `(i, j, k)` is a triplet such that the sum,
>   `S = A[i] + A[j] + A[k]`, is divisible by exactly one of `A[i]`, `A[j]`, or `A[k]`.
>
> Array values of a triplet `(i,j,k)` is `(A[i], A[j], A[k])`.
>
> input: `N=4 A=[1,2,2,1]`
>
> output: `12`
>
> Explanation : `S=2+2+1=5` is divisible only by number `1` in the triplet and the triplet with array values `1, 1, 2` is not a good triplet as `S = 4` is divisible by all three. So there are two triplets `(1,2,2)` and `(2,2,1)`. Look at the `i`,`j`,`k` values which are indices. So, there are 12 possibilities of triplets of indices that can have array values as `2`, `2`, `1`. They are:
>   (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (3, 1, 2), (2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1), 
>   (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 4), (4, 2, 3), (3, 4, 2), (4, 3, 2).
>   I tried this (but i want to decrease the time complexity):

```
def good_triplets (arr, n):
    c=0
    for i in range(0,n-2):
        for j in range(i+1,n-1):
            for k in range(j+1,n):
                sum=arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k]
                if(sum%arr[i]==0 and sum%arr[j]!=0 and sum%arr[k]!=0):
                    c=c+1
                elif(sum%arr[j]==0 and sum%arr[k]!=0 and sum%arr[i]!=0):
                    c=c+1
                elif(sum%arr[k]==0 and sum%arr[i]!=0 and sum%arr[j]!=0):
                    c=c+1
    return(c*6)

n = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(n) : 
    x = int(input())
    arr.append(x)
out_ = good_triplets(arr, n)
print (out_)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the question? Show us what yozu have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: Used 3 nested for loops, then if else conditions..due to 3 nested for loops  time complexity=O(n3)

Comment: i want more efficient solution without using itertools combinations

Comment: Your predicate is weird. `1 < i , j , k < N` means that neither index N or 1 is possible, but you use both index 4 and 1 in the example :|

Comment: sorry let me correct

Comment: Are the numbers all positive?

Comment: Please [EDIT] your question to include what you've tried. If you want it reviewed, there's a separate site for that

Comment: yes all numbers are positive @v78

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Its actually easier to just copy paste the code..

Comment: What is the range of numbers?

Comment: Observations: (1) a divides a+b+c if and only if a divides b+c. (2) You can avoid computing things like sum%a many times. Compute its once, just like you computed sum only once. (3) The case of all numbers dividing the sum is not necessary, since already it would be excluded from the count by some of the cases in which the sum if divisible by two of the numbers. (4) Since the intend of c=c is to do nothing, then write nothing. By writing something you risk the possibility that the computer might be doing something, slowing you down.

Comment: Inside your loops, you can compute `x,y,z = ((arr[i]+arr[j])%arr[k] == 0), ((arr[i]+arr[k])%arr[j] == 0),((arr[j]+arr[k])%arr[i] == 0)` and then do `if ((x^y^x) and not (x and y and z)): c += 1`.

Comment: i want to decrease the time complexity @conditionalMethod

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no possible way to do this without checking every possible combination, which is still `O(n^3)` (or (n*(n-1)*(n-2))/6). You mostly only make the code a bit nicer and "hide" the complexity in a function, if you use itertools combinations. If you still want a solution, I can give you one.. but its not that much quicker, if at all.

Comment: But they not accepting this solution (time complexity error)and import statements are not allowed @Artog 46

Answer (score 2):

As per the question, there can be duplicate as well as unique values in the array eg. [6,6,4,3].
To get an optimized solution the algorithm is divided into two major parts- unique values, duplicate values.
(Main Idea) Remove the duplicates and keep their counts. Numbers are less than 100. Hence time complexity will reduce a lot.

```
def good_triplets(arr, n):
    dict1 = {}  // to keep count of each element
    nums = []   // to keep unique entries of each element
    for i in range(0, n):
        if dict1.get(int(arr[i])) is None:
            dict1[int(arr[i])] = 1
            nums.append(int(arr[i]))
        else:
            dict1[int(arr[i])] = dict1[int(arr[i])] + 1
    count = 0   //count of good triplets
    n = len(nums)

    // for every entry occuring atleast once in the given array (unique entry) [6,4,3]
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            sum = nums[i] + nums[j]
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                sum += nums[k]
                c = 0
                if sum % nums[i] == 0:
                    c += 1
                if sum % nums[j] == 0:
                    c += 1
                if sum % nums[k] == 0:
                    c += 1
                if c == 1:
                    count += dict1[nums[i]] * dict1[nums[j]] * dict1[nums[k]]  //total count depends on how many times i,j,k appears in the actual array

    // for every entry occuring more than once in the given array (duplicate entries) eg.[6]
    for i in range(0, n):
        if dict1[nums[i]] < 2: // not to be executed for unique entries as they are already taken care of
            continue
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i == j:
                continue
            sum = nums[i] * 2 + nums[j] // i will be the duplicate element and j will be our third element in the triplet
            if sum % nums[i] != 0 and sum % nums[j] ==0:  // if the sum is divisible only by the third element (j)
                count += ((dict1[nums[i]] * (dict1[nums[i]] - 1)) / 2) * dict1[nums[j]]
    return count*6

n = int(input())
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    arr.append(x)

good_triplet_count = good_triplets(arr, n)
print(good_triplet_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which runs in O(10^6) complexity. The hint was in *A[i]<=100*.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> getpossiblenumbers(){
    int i,j,k;
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=100;j++){
            for(k=1;k<=100;k++)
            {
                int sum=i+j+k;
                if((sum%i==0 && sum%j!=0 && sum%k!=0)||
                    (sum%j==0 && sum%i!=0 && sum%k!=0)||
                    (sum%k==0 && sum%i!=0 && sum%j!=0))
                v.push_back({i,j,k});
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

In this section what I did is ran 3 loops checked all the possibility of possible triplets with given constraints that should be divisible by only one of i, j and k. All possible combinations of triplets won't be much.

```
long long good_triplets (vector<int> arr, int n) {
   vector<vector<int>> v = getpossiblenumbers();
   long long i,j,k,ans=0;
   map<long long,long long> m1;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       m1[arr[i]]++;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
       if(m1[v[i][0]]>0 && m1[v[i][1]]>0 && m1[v[i][2]]>0)
       {
            if(v[i][0]==v[i][1])
            ans+=((m1[v[i][0]]*(m1[v[i][1]]-1)*m1[v[i][2]]));
            else if(v[i][1]==v[i][2])
            ans+=((m1[v[i][0]]*(m1[v[i][1]]-1)*m1[v[i][2]]));
            else if(v[i][0]==v[i][2])
            ans+=((m1[v[i][1]]*(m1[v[i][0]]-1)*m1[v[i][2]]));
            else
            ans+=(m1[v[i][0]]*m1[v[i][1]]*m1[v[i][2]]);
       }    
   }
   return ans;
}
```

In this good_triplet method first I stored the frequency count of each number in a map.
 Then iterated our previously created vector with 3 possible *i, j, k*. 
All the 3 *i, j, k* can't be equal because sum is divisible by only one and we have taken care of this in **getpossiblenumbers** function.
 But when two of i, j and k are equal take care of counts as I did in 3 cases above. keep adding in the answer variable.

```
int main() {

    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for(int i_arr=0; i_arr<n; i_arr++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i_arr];
    }
    long long out_;
    out_ = good_triplets(arr, n);
    cout << out_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int binomialCoeff(int n, int k) 
{ 
    vector<int> C(k+1,0); 

    C[0] = 1;  // nC0 is 1 

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    { 
        // Compute next row of pascal triangle using 
        // the previous row 
        for (int j = min(i, k); j > 0; j--) 
            C[j] = C[j] + C[j-1]; 
    } 
    return C[k]; 
}

long countGoodTriplets(vector<int> a)
{
    int n = a.size();
    int threeFactorial=6;
    int elSize = 100;
    long goodTriplets = 0;
    vector<int> count(elSize,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        count[a[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i=1;i<elSize-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<elSize;j++)
        {
            for(int k=j+1;k<elSize+1;k++)
            {
                    if(count[i]!=0 && count[j]!=0&& count[k]!=0)
                    {
                    int flag=0;
                    //int sum = i+j+k;
                    if((i+j)%k==0) //sum%k
                    flag++;
                    if((k+j)%i==0)//sum%i
                    flag++;
                    if((i+k)%j==0)//sum%j
                    flag++;

                    if(flag==1)
                    {
                        //cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<k<<endl;
                        goodTriplets += threeFactorial;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
      for(int i=1;i<elSize;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<elSize+1;j++)
        {

           if( count[i]>1 && ((2*i))%j ==0 && (j%i!=0)) 
           {
               goodTriplets+=(threeFactorial * (binomialCoeff(count[i],2)));
           }
           if( count[j]>1 && ((2*j))%i ==0 && (i%j!=0)) 
           {
               goodTriplets+=(threeFactorial * (binomialCoeff(count[j],2)));
           }

        }
    }
    return goodTriplets;
}

int main() {
    //code
    vector<int> vect{ 1,2,4 }; 
    cout<<calc(vect);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Expected output is wrong. Can you please look into it once.